# Media Size, please stop resetting. (Adobe Illustrator Print Settings)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm printing a bunch of sheets that have need usual print settings, and every single print, I have to go back and re-set the Media Size in the print dialog. If I forget, the print fails in a way that requires a full reboot and manual clean-up of the printer queue.

[image]

How can I get Illustrator to preserve my Media Size setting?

Comment: Commenting for clarification: I'm printing on 300+gsm paper, which my printer will only accept when set to the single-sheet manual rear feeder. So I have to start a new print job for each individual sheet. All the custom settings that it takes to get this paper through the printer hinge on the print being set to Manual Rear, and it unsets itself after every single print.

If I miss this setting, the print fails, and leaves behind a bad print in the queue. I have to power down the printer, clear a jam, clear the print queue manually, power the printer back up, reset the guide, and start anew.

Answer (score 1):

You can **save a print preset** and use that....

Set things how you want, then click the little "save to disk" icon next to the print preset drop down...

[image]

The print preset *will* be saved with the file. Therefore, once it's selected for a print the first time, it should remain the "default" option for that file in the future. So, for future files, you can just select the, now saved, print preset the first time you print the file.

If you want *all* prints to default to these settings, choose `Edit > Print Presets` then click the `[Default]` preset and then the little `Edit` icon...

[image: print]

Set things how you want the default print dialog to appear and save.